# Generating tests for all-pairs testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, automated-tests

I have a short (Java) method with several parameters that performs some non-intuitive computation. Writing unit tests for this method in order to achieve code coverage is trivial, but the tests don't cover the subtleties of the method. I am looking for a testing framework or some other tool that will allow me to do all-pairs (all-tuples) testing for this method, based on partitions that I define for the parameters.

For example, suppose I have the following method:

```
int foo(int begin, int end, int first, int last) {
    ...
}
```

I already know some constraints, which may be enforced externally:

```
begin <= end
first <= last
```

I want to define explicit equivalence relations, based on my own knowledge of the parameters. For example:

```
begin == MIN
begin > MIN && begin < 0
begin == 0
begin == 1
begin > 1 && begin < MAX
begin == MAX
```

I would also like to define equivalence relations involving more than one parameter. For example:

```
begin + 1 < end
begin + 1 == end
begin == end
```

A combination to test is the selection of an equivalence class from each of the equivalence relations (e.g., `begin == 0` from the first relation and `begin + 1 < end` from the second relation), such that the constraints are satisfiable. [Incidentally, I realize satisfiability is NP-complete. I'm willing to live with it, given combinations that comprise a relatively small set of constraints.] With several parameters, the number of combinations becomes unwieldy. Manually writing a test for each combination and finding arguments that satisfy the resultant set of constraints is tedious and error prone.

I'm looking for a testing framework that can automatically test each combination, or a test generator that can generate a test for each logically consistent combination (invariant checks to be inserted by yours truly). This is different from test-generation tools like [CodePro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/junit/test_case_generation), which generate test cases from the actual implementation. Effectively, I want to generate tests for an interface of the method, rather than its implementation. Not only would this allow me to write the tests before the method is implemented (TDD), but it would ensure the method is comprehensively tested even after its later modification.

Does such a tool exist, or can something be kludged together? Or perhaps I'm approaching this the wrong way, and you have another suggestion...

Comment: How will you know the result is correct without reimplementing the method as part of the testing code?

Comment: @jnnnnn: If I have a separate unit test for each combination, each test can have its own invariants. So, I need a way to declaratively specify the invariants for the various combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [David Saff's](http://saffgreenbar.blogspot.com/) work on [Theory Testing](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/40090) for some ideas on this.

Comment: Excellent find. Saff's work is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for, and I was unaware of the Theory additions to JUnit (albeit experimental). Though it's not a generator, I believe I can slap something together that builds on top of this.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't simple nested loops, where a test method is invoked at each innermost loop iteration, fit the bill (or at least mostly fit the bill)?

Something like:

```
int[] ends = new int[] {-50, -10, -1, 0, 1, 50, MIN, MAX};
for (int end : ends) {
    int[] begins = new int[] {end - 10, end - 1, end, MIN, MAX};
    for (int begin : begins) {
        if (begin <= end && begin >= MIN && begin <= MAX) {
             testFoo(begin, end);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work for partitions involving only one parameter. Partitions involving multiple parameters could be handled by simply enumerating the only those combinations as successive `if` statements inside the loops. I'm left with the problem of specifying the invariant checks without simply reimplementing the method inside `testFoo`, though.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a tool outside your test framework? If so, I've used [James Bach's AllPairs](http://www.satisfice.com/tools.shtml) with good results. There's also [Hexawise](http://hexawise.com/).

If you weren't aware of it, http://pairwise.org is a great place to read on pairwise and combinatorial testing and tools!

Comment: Thanks, very helpful links. I should be using JUnit, but I can always advocate for something else

Comment: Clarity fail... What I meant was: use one of those tools to create your data, then pipe it/pass it in to your JUnit tests!

Comment: Ah, misunderstood. I was perusing the list from pairwise, and saw things like SpecExplorer, and thought they were generating test cases for specific tools. I see now that most of them are more generic.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still interested in libraries that perform combinatorial tests under JUnit framework.
I recently implemented a library 'JCUnit', which does exactly it.

It generates test cases under JUnit and run the test method with them.

http://dakusui.github.io/jcunit/

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest that if you TDDed the algorithm, then you already likely have sufficient test coverage. If anyone subsequently comes in and changes the algorithm, you should see at least one of the original tests break. If you have some edge conditions to test, you could write a couple, but if these edges aren't interesting enough to turn red once you've added them, then they probably aren't interesting enough to keep around and duplicate the existing tests. Redundant tests are less valuable and I tend to delete them.

Comment: I'm not one inclined to remove redundant tests, unless they test identical input. Just my personal methodology. Regardless, I'm kind of stuck with respect to determining which tests to write initially. Plenty of tools generate "test after" tests, but I don't know of one that generates "test before" tests.